# Button remains clicked on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

I need a idea how to solve the following issue.

I'm working on a like/dislike system of a blog posts which remembers what user liked only in the local storage.

**The problem is, that when I like the post, button becomes disabled (as it should), but when I reload the page the number of likes increases (the like button remains clicked). How can I solve this ?**

---

```
<!-- Likes button -->   
                    <button id="likebtn" type="button">                  
                            <input type="number" id="input1" value ="<?php echo $post_likes;?>"</input>    
                    </button>


                    </p>
                        <script>
                            let likebtn = document.querySelector('#likebtn');
                            let input = document.querySelector('#input1'); 

                            //local storage - saving ID of liked post
                            var likedID = parseInt('<?php echo $link_post_id ?>');
                            var likedIDhistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrayOfLikedPosts")) || [];
                            var isLiked = false;

                            for (var i = 0; i < likedIDhistory.length; i++){
                                var arrayLS = JSON.parse(localStorage["arrayOfLikedPosts"]);
                                var actual = arrayLS[i];
                                
                                if(likedID == actual) {
                                    isLiked= true;
                                    console.log("true");
                                }                            
                            }

                            //if is not liked by "user"
                            if (isLiked == false) {                                                       
       
                            likebtn.addEventListener('click', likes_function=>
                            {
                            input1.value = <?php echo $post_likes?> + 1;
                            input.style.color = "#a1c4fd";

                            <?php
                            $like_query = "UPDATE posts SET post_likes_count=post_likes_count +1 WHERE post_id=$link_post_id";
                            $send_query2 = mysqli_query($connection, $like_query);

                            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=$link_post_id";
                            $like_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
                            ?>  

                            likedIDhistory.push(likedID);
                            localStorage.setItem("arrayOfLikedPosts", JSON.stringify(likedIDhistory));
                            document.getElementById("likebtn").disabled = true;
                            document.getElementById("likebtn").style.opacity=0.5; 
                         });


                            //if is already liked by "user"
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById("likebtn").disabled = true;
                                document.getElementById("likebtn").style.opacity=0.5;
                            }                  

                        </script>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In your `script` tag you have a `<?php` code which always updates the like count:

```php
<?php
  $like_query = "UPDATE posts SET post_likes_count=post_likes_count +1 WHERE post_id=$link_post_id";
  $send_query2 = mysqli_query($connection, $like_query);

  $query2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=$link_post_id";
  $like_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
?>
```

It seems you intended the PHP code to only execute in the `likebtn.addEventListener` from JavaScript. This is not how that works.

The PHP code is always executed - it does not know you are within some code in JavaScript. PHP and JavaScript do not work with each other that way.
This is why it is always counting up.

You can send a request to another PHP script which counts the value up and refreshes the button.

The localstorage implementation you speak of is not present in your code, so I cannot speak about that. But this is surely the error you describe in your question title.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task you need to add the following code in your file for like and dislike and saving in Local Storage

```js
$(".like-btn").click( function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  event.preventDefault();

});



$(".panel-group_btn span").click(function(){
                       var btnStorage = $(this).attr("id");

                        if($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
                            localStorage.setItem(btnStorage, 'true');
                        } else {
                            localStorage.removeItem(btnStorage, 'true');
                        }

                    });


                    $( ".panel-group_btn span" ).each(function() {
                      var mainlocalStorage = $( this ).attr( "id" );

                      if(localStorage.getItem(mainlocalStorage) == 'true') {
                        $(this).addClass("clicked");
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
                    }



                    });
```

```css
body, a {font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"; text-decoration:none;
}


a.panel-group_btn {color: #888;display:block;}

a.like-btn {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 14px;
}


span.clicked {
  color: #00dfae; 
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Like button</h1>

<p>Uses the span's id to name the Local Storage key. Check Local Storage in your inspector to see the saved keys.</p>

<a  class="panel-group_btn" href="#" >
    <span id="like-01" class="like-btn">
    Like
    </span>
</a>

<a  class="panel-group_btn" href="#" >
    <span id="like-02" class="like-btn">
    Like
    </span>
</a>

<a  class="panel-group_btn" href="#">
    <span id="like-03" class="like-btn">
    Like
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: You should not code entire solutions for people here. They should learn / improve by themselves.